# Router Connect with Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

```
Router::connect(
    'mylogin',
    array('controller' => 'User', 'action' => 'xyz', 5)
);
```

How do I create a an array  `array('controller' => 'User', 'action' => 'xyz', 5)` from a string I have stored in database as /User/xyz/5

Can I have a way to connect route by string instead of array?

Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

try to split your string using this code. I hope that it helps you. :)

```
$split = explode('/', '/User/xyz/5');
Router::connect('mylogin',array('controller' => $split[1], 'action' => $split[2], $split[3]));
```

Comment: You are missing a delimiter, and if you would use the proper delimiter, your indices were wrong as the first entry would be empty.

Comment: oppps! sorry, I totally forgot about it. Thanks! :D